# Click event for flipview or swipe view

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement the Click event for fragments that display images or buttons.

I am able to implement the flip view to get another fragment but I am unable get the click event working on such fragments.

I have tried with android:onClick, even setting `clickable` to `true`. I even tried with onClickListener and onTouch but it's not firing for me.

This is the code I have tried.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private FlipViewGroup contentView;
public int currentimageindex=0;
 private GestureDetector mDetector;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // hde staitbar otef Andoroid
        // could also be usdne lar
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setTitle(R.string.activity_title);
    contentView = new FlipViewGroup(this);
    contentView.addFlipView(View.inflate(this, R.layout.second_page, null));
    contentView.addFlipView(View.inflate(this, R.layout.first_page, null)); 
    setContentView(contentView);
//  setContentView(R.layout.second_page);
    contentView.startFlipping(); //make the first_page view flipping        
    ImageView imgFavorite =   (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imgFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "The favorite list would appear on clicking this icon",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });      
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    contentView.onResume();
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    contentView.onPause();
}   
public void onclick(View v){
    ImageView imgFavorite =   (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imgFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "The favorite list would appear on clicking this icon",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }); 
}
}
```

This is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/white">                
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
android:src="@drawable/android"
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="onclick"/>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there some reason a fragment within a flip view doesn't respond to click or touch events, or is there something I'm doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Please elaborate more

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, FlipViewGroup is your custom view group implementation.
If that is the case you need onInterceptTouchEvent() see the sample code here.
http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html